# Virtual Host Forbidden enabled SSL

Tags: apache-2.4, node.js

I want to run nodeJs server on virtual host. If I don't use https everything is working. But when I use https I get forbidden error. How can I solve?

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost api.*****.com:443> 
    ServerName api.*****.com
    DocumentRoot /home/***/Desktop/api.****.com/

    <Directory /home/***/Desktop/api.****.com/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        RewriteEngine On
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_api.**.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_api.**_com_key
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>   
    ServerName api.****.com.tr  
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Check the Apache error log.

Comment: The port 443 vHost you posted does not have _any_ proxy directives? It is also seeming for a different host?